# Making a SKSpriteNode platform that recognize when a SKSprite is outside of it

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, sprite-kit

I'm trying to make a random type platform (based on the shape of the sprite that I put) in where the main character of my game would be situated; if an enemy passes the platform shape, it will be removed (like it was fallen). Here is an image of what I want to say:

[image]
The blue dot will be the hero character, the red ones the bad guys; the one that is inside a purple circle is the one that should be removed when falling out of the circular platform

So basically, I don't know how to detect properly when a charater is falling, I have something now, but they fall when all the body is fallen:

```
- (void) boundsCheck:(SKSpriteNode*)sprite{
    CGPoint newPosition = self.position;
    CGPoint newVelocity = self.velocity;

    CGPoint bottomLeft = CGPointMake(sprite.frame.origin.x, sprite.frame.origin.y);
    CGPoint topRight = CGPointMake(sprite.frame.origin.x + sprite.size.width,
                                   sprite.frame.origin.y + sprite.size.height);

    if (newPosition.x <= bottomLeft.x) {
        [self removeCharacterWithPosition:newPosition];
    }
    if (newPosition.x >= topRight.x) {
        [self removeCharacterWithPosition:newPosition];
    }
    if (newPosition.y <= bottomLeft.y) {
        [self removeCharacterWithPosition:newPosition];
    }
    if (newPosition.y >= topRight.y) {
        [self removeCharacterWithPosition:newPosition];
    }

    self.position = newPosition;
    self.velocity = newVelocity;
}
```

Can you tell me some tips? Thanks

Comment: I tried, but dont understand what you want... how do u mean if an enemy passes the platform shape. Can you just use a vector length from hero and enemy ? and if > than "set dist" it is removed ?

Comment: @Smick right now I'm comparing the shape of the frame, but it's very odd how it's done, I want something more exactly... sorry if I didn't explained myself

Comment: so if the red dot moves outside the black circle its is removed ? How are you moving the red dots ?

Answer (score 0):

If the platform is exactly circular you could check the distance of the red dots from the platform center. If their distance is bigger than the platform radius you can consider them out of the platform. To check the distance between two CGPoints (which are used to store the position property of nodes) you can use a function like this:

```
- (float)distanceBetween : (CGPoint) centerOfPlatform and: (CGPoint)enemy
{
    return sqrt(pow(p2.x-p1.x,2)+pow(p2.y-p1.y,2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple, there is a method called: `containsPoint` with that I could detect if the CGPont of the enemy is inside or not of the platform :) so I made it:

```
 if ([bezierPath containsPoint:newPosition]) {
        self.position = newPosition;
        self.velocity = newVelocity;
        return;
    }
```

thanks for the answers!